# Esxi lists two disks instead of one RAID1

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi

I'm trying to install Esxi on a Dell PowerEdge R210 II.

I enabled RAID in bios and then created RAID1 (CTRL+R at boot). This part is OK.

But the Esxi wizard lists  two disks when I need to select where to install the OS. It should list only one virtual disk instead.

What have I done wrong ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

ESXi doesn't support "fake" software aka host RAID. Get a decent, certified RAID controller.

https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=io

Comment: Thank you for your answer even though it doesn't make me happy.